# ListBox and exception when populating ItemsSource

Tags: c#, asynchronous, listbox, async-await, windows-phone-8.1

I have been struggling myself for few hours about an exception (two of them) I get. The problem seems to be concerning device (I'm using *Lumia 820*, debug/release mode doesn't matter) with WP8.1 - on emulator works fine (I've not tested much). It is also very hard to track and reproduce - so I [add complete code in case somebody wants to try](http://1drv.ms/1lxEo7c).

I've a *ListBox* which is populated with a button:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    List<string> populationOfItems = new List<string>();
    ObservableCollection<string> itemsToView = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        first.Click += first_Click;
        myList.ItemsSource = itemsToView;
        myList.SelectionChanged += myList_SelectionChanged;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) populationOfItems.Add("Item " + i.ToString());
        BottomAppBar = new CommandBar();
    }

    private void first_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        itemsToView.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            itemsToView.Add("Example " + i.ToString());
    }
```

That works ok. Then when I select item, I want to change my ObservableCollection:

```cs
private async void myList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myList.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        itemsToView.Clear();
        await PopulateList();
    }
}

private async Task PopulateList()
{
    await Task.Delay(100); // running asynchronous seems to make a problem
    itemsToView.Add("FIRSTELEMENT");
    foreach (var item in populationOfItems)
        itemsToView.Add(item);
}
```

Here goes the problem - pattern to reproduce:

- click first button to populate Listbox
- scroll down Listbox
- when Listbox moving down (try few times to restart if problem hadn't occured) hit Item 9 for example.

I get the following exception:

[image: First one]

What is also weird, after a while (when you click somewhere else with a mouse) and then try to look at exception once more - it changes to:

[image: Second one]

The problem seems to be somehow concerned with asynchronous run of `Task PopulateList()` (that is why I also tagged this question `asynchronous`) - if it's run synchronous without the line `await Task.Delay(100);`, it seems to work ok.

Does anybody have an idea what can be wrong?

**EDIT** - a little bit of more informarion

I'm unuable to catch the exception with any try-catch block.

I've also tried to populate Collection via `Dispatcher` - without success.

I've tried to populate first a temporary `List<string>` and then after finishing `await PopulateList();`, copy items to `ObservableCollection` - this also hadn't helped.

Comment: Try solving your [other problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212044/listbox-inability-to-select-the-first-element-after-populating-itemssource/23232688#23232688) first and see if this one get's solved.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Look, that maybe somebody knows the answer to this problem and it would solve the other one. The problems may bo connected as it is the same Control, but this one IMO is far worse - it generates exception, which I'm unable to catch. Both problems are somehow connected with async, but may have totally different reason. I've also tried to run this via `Dispatcher` without success. It's a matter of luck that I've enocuntered two problems at one time.

Comment: When many problems occur in the same code, most of the time it's the same cause.

Comment: I agree that the problems may be caused by the same (my) mistake. But [the other problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23212044/2681948) can be easily 'repaired' by the user - by 'bouncing' (scrolling up/down) the ListBox. It is different in this case - that's why I try to find answer separately. If somebodys answer would solve both issues then I would be very happy to accept it for both questions.