# Listbox - inability to select the first element after populating ItemsSource

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm working on WP8.1 and I've found strage behaviour of my Listbox - to make it easier to reproduce I've put [the code here](http://1drv.ms/1lxIufB). The problem occurs both on device and emulator.

I've a Listbox which is bound to ObservableCollection and it is filled with items upon button click:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    List<string> populationOfItems = new List<string>();
    ObservableCollection<string> itemsToView = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        second.Click += second_Click;
        myList.ItemsSource = itemsToView;
        // populate list of items to be copied
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) populationOfItems.Add("Item " + i.ToString());
        BottomAppBar = new CommandBar();
    }

    private async void second_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        itemsToView.Clear();
        await PopulateList();
    }

    private async Task PopulateList()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100); // without this line code seems to work ok
        itemsToView.Add("FIRSTELEMENT"); // add first differet element
        foreach (var item in populationOfItems)
            itemsToView.Add(item);
    }
}
```

The first time I fill the list, everthing is ok (pic. 1). But when I hit the button second time and, I can see elements not from first but from second (pic. 2). Ok - it is above, but I'm anable to scroll to it, when I hold my finger (mouse) I can scroll list and see that it exists, but when I stop scrolling the list hides (scrolls to second element) the first element. Also when you select any item - the list seems to look ok while you hold your finger (pic. 3), when you release it hides the first element again. When you move the list few time up/down, it repairs and works normal.

The way to reproduce the issue:

- click the scond button once - fill the list
- scroll list down, so that you hide the first elements (**this is important**)
- hit the second button once more
- try to scroll the list up and see first element, release finger

Pic.1
[image]

Pic.2
[image]

Pic.3
[image]

The problem seems to be concerned with asynchronous Task (that is why I also tagged this question asynchronous) - without the line `await Task.Delay(100);`, the code seems to work ok.

Does anybody have an idea what can be wrong?

**EDIT** - some other attempts

I've also tried running populating process via `Dispatcher`, without success - the problem exists.

I've also made an attempt to populate a temporary `List` (not ObservableCollection) and after returning from `async Task`, populate ObservableCollection - the problem persists.

```
List<string> temporaryList = new List<string>();
private async Task PopulateList()
{
    await Task.Delay(100); // without this line code seems to work ok
    temporaryList.Clear();
    temporaryList.Add("FIRSTELEMENT"); // add first differet element
    foreach (var item in populationOfItems)
        temporaryList.Add(item);
}

private async void second_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    itemsToView.Clear();
    await PopulateList();
    foreach (var item in temporaryList)
       itemsToView.Add(item);
}
```

**Edit 2** - returnig List created in acync Task also doesn't help much:

```
private async void second_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    itemsToView.Clear();
    var items = await PopulateList();
    foreach (var item in items)
        itemsToView.Add(item);
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> PopulateList()
{
    await Task.Delay(100); // without this line code seems to work ok
    List<string> temporaryList = new List<string>();
    temporaryList.Add("FIRSTELEMENT"); // add first differet element
    foreach (var item in populationOfItems)
        temporaryList.Add(item);
    return temporaryList;
}
```

**EDIT 3** - as I've checked the same code run under Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix UI handling with data retrieval because they are now happening concurrently.

Be also aware that when you call `await PopulateList()` the execution flow goes back to the UI thread and is ready to accept clicks and fire click events.

Try this instead:

```
private async void second_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // UI thread
    var items = await PopulateListAsync(); // -> return to UI thread
    // back to UI thread
    itemsToView.Clear();
    itemsToView.Add("FIRSTELEMENT"); // add first differet element
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        itemsToView.Add(item);
    }
}

private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> PopulateListAsync()
{
    // caller thread - UI thread
    await Task.Delay(100)
        .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    // some other thread
    return populationOfItems;
}
```

You might want to read this:

- [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)
- [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh873175.aspx)
- [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

**EDIT:**

I believe this demonstrates what you're trying to do. I've added a few more delays for you to see it happening on the phone.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="List" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" LayoutMode="List">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
            <Button Content="Button" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" x:Name="Button1"/>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private List<string> populationOfItems = new List<string>
        {
            "one",
            "two",
            "three",
            "four",
            "five"
        };
        private ObservableCollection<string> itemsToView = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this.itemsToView;
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Button1.IsEnabled = false;
            var items = await PopulateListAsync();
            itemsToView.Clear();
            await Task.Delay(100);
            itemsToView.Add("FIRSTELEMENT");
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10);
                itemsToView.Add(item);
            }
            this.Button1.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> PopulateListAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(100)
                .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
            return populationOfItems;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm aware of this what you have said. It was my first thought that it may be concerned with 'other thread' - so I tried running populating process via `Dispatcher` (if you had downloaded my code then you should see there second method with Dispatcher). Nothing helped. Please also see my edit to the question - I've also tried via separate temporary list not connected with UI = nothing helped. As for me the problem seems to be with Listbox itself and maybe its animation - but I'm not sure - maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you try the approach I recommend?

Comment: Yes, I've tried - your example just returns a reference to List which isn't modified (and I need to modify it within async Task - that is what it was created for). I followed your proposal (see my second edit), but the problem persits. Have you got any idea?

Comment: There is also other question - the emelents are in the ListBox - if you croll it up you can see them (try to run example with more elements for example 12 - it is even more funny). And second thing - if you 'bounce' the ListBox (scroll fast up/down) - it rapairs itself and now you can sroll normally.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my code mimics yours minus the part that eliminates concurrent access to `itemsToView`. How is `itemsToView` bound to the `ListBox`?

Comment: Listbox ItemTemplate is an image (static source) and Textblock with `Text="{Binding}"` - the simple case. Then by setting ItemsSource to ObservableCollection DataContext is set. Yes I agree with your point. But in Edit 2, I've eliminated access to `itemsToView` from the `Task` and the problem persists. That's why I'm confused, strange is also that Listbox scroll unblocks after few tries.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I haven't noticed your edit. Please not that my code was running under WinRT, and I used ListBox. I was already using similar code in WP8.0 and it was running fine so I've just checked it uner WP8.1 Silverlight and there is no such an issue.